# How to have Visual Studio 2015 cope with Microsoft's 2019 symbol server upgrade?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, symbol-server

I find something abnormal inside my Windows 7's VS2015 IDE recently. When starting debugging, VS2015 can no longer fetch pdb files from Microsoft's symbol server. This happens around the end of 2019.

Screen shot below:

[image: VS2015 on win7 fail on MS symbol server upgrade]

[image]

After some investigation, I find out that pristine pdb file URL http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/wntdll.pdb/E611E9E16BA54434A45EB38CE9217A792/wntdll.pdb now becomes redirected to sth like [https://vsblobprodscussu5shard65.blob.core.windows.net/b-4712e...](https://vsblobprodscussu5shard65.blob.core.windows.net/b-4712e0edc5a240eabf23330d7df68e77/4BD123DFC88A46A29C9B891C015AD4BC494E7C0D9F37CD627544978AB11BF52300.blob?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&si=1&sig=NKsGZdPPn7zYyZDnewUsSv24g7GdguyglM3X2PAg5lM%3D&spr=https&se=2020-04-11T04%3A17%3A47Z&rscl=x-e2eid-cb4bc8e4-f5764762-bddb0627-93774c89-session-559100c7-a3f149f9-b3bc7ddf-ab1ba6a7) . 
And the old VS2015(with update 3) seems unable to follow that HTTP redirection, so it complains about **ERROR_INTERNET_HTTP_TO_HTTPS_ON_REDIR** .

No doubt it is due to back-end infrastructure upgrade of Microsoft's symbol server.

Of course, using the updated windbg.exe from EWDK 1903, I can download symbols for those system DLLs, but that's quite inconvenient when my most debugging work in done in Visual Studio.

So my question is: Is there way/patch to have VS2015 debugger work with the new symbol server?

## ============ 2020.04.20 Update ===========

Strange, after I play with VS2015 and windbg back and forth several times for about one hour, VS2015 pdb downloading starts to work suddenly. There must have been some mysterious change behind the scene!

Comment: Works just fine when I try it, `SYMSRV:  wgdi32.pdb from https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 380928 bytes`.  But is Win10.  Looks to me like you got malware on that machine that blocks the redirect to https, try disabling it.

Comment: I don't think I have malware in my Win7 VM. The **ERROR_INTERNET_HTTP_TO_HTTPS_ON_REDIR** error is a sign of old version of windbg software suite. For example, using symchk.exe from WDK 10.0.10240, `symchk /v c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll /s` will definitely spout ERROR_INTERNET_HTTP_TO_HTTPS_ON_REDIR, and swtiching to symchk.exe from EWDK 1903 works immediately -- as I have tried myself.

Comment: use HTTPs and not HTTP